# Insert multiple values with different select criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Is there a method for inserting multiple values when each value has to get some information first from another table?

For example I have two tables

- interests = id,subject1
- userinterests = id,userid,interestid

data for the tables might look like this

#### interests example table

```
id  interests
-------------
1   cats  
2   mysql  
3   php
```

#### userinterests example table

```
id  user   interest_id
----------------------
1   dan    1            -- dan is interested in cats  
2   johan  2            -- johan is interested in mysql   
3   joe    1            -- joe is interested in cats
```

I find out that new user Hayley is interested in American Idol and beards

#### interests example table

```
id  interests
-------------
1   cats  
2   mysql  
3   php  
4   American Idol  
5   beards
```

I want to then update the userInterest database to add

```
id  user     interest_id
------------------------
4   hayley   4          -- hayley is interested in American Idol  
5   hayley   5          -- hayley is interested in beards
```

but I can't because I don't know what the interest id's are for American Idol and beards?

I want to insert all of Hayleys interests at once in some sort of multiple insert query.

```
INSERT into userInterests   
  Values(hayley, --whatever the id from table interests for "American Idol")  
  Values(hayley, --whatever the id from table interests for "beards")
```

I guess I would use SELECT somewhere but not sure where.  Could someone provide me with an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO userInterests 
SELECT DEFAULT, 'hayley', i.id
  FROM INTERESTS i
 WHERE i.subject1 IN ('American Idol', 'beards')
```

`DEFAULT` is because I assume that the `id` column is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: How would the query change if there were 3 subjects instead of 1. Would I do WHERE i.subject1 IN ('American Idol','Beards') AND i.subject2 IN ('American Idol','Beards')...

Comment: @daniel savage: It's possible, but the database setup (columns) isn't ideal.

Comment: @Elprup, your suggested edit should probably be a new answer, or a comment on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
INSERT INTO userInterests VALUES
(hayley, SELECT id FROM interests WHERE subject1 = "American Idol"), 
(hayley, SELECT id FROM interests WHERE subject1 = "beards");
```

Putting, instead of `hayley`, the hayley's id (you didn't say what is the type of it, so I don't know).

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but I wonder if there's a more succinct way to write it.

Comment: i'm getting errors with the syntax you provided replacing hayley with a query to select hayley's id from the table users(id,name) by doing this  Select id from users where name='hayley'.  I can run each select query separately, but combining them with insert into ...values (select 1,select 2) does not seem to work???

Comment: @daniel savage: Which is why you use the syntax in the answer I provided.

Comment: When doing this, the SELECT must always return only one value, so you can do SELECT MAX(id), for example, to show your DBMS that query will always return a suitable value for the id.